# Gunicorn socket disappears

Tags: sockets, unix, nginx, gunicorn

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS
Release:    12.04
Codename:   precise

gunicorn (version 19.1.1)
nginx version: nginx/1.1.19
```

My gunicorn conf:

```
bind = ["unix:///tmp/someproj1.sock", "unix:///tmp/someproj2.sock"]
pythonpath = "/home/deploy/someproj/someproj"
workers = 5
worker_class = "eventlet"
worker_connections = 25
timeout = 3600
graceful_timeout = 3600
```

We started getting 502s at around 2PM yesterday in our dev env. This was in the Nginx error log:

```
connect() to unix:///tmp/someproj1.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream"
```

Both gunicorn sockets were missing from /tmp.

At 11:55AM today I ran `ps -eo pid,cmd,etime|grep gunicorn` to get the uptime:

```
4156 gunicorn: master [myproj.    22:53:54
4161 gunicorn: worker [myproj.    22:53:54
4162 gunicorn: worker [myproj.    22:53:54
4163 gunicorn: worker [myproj.    22:53:54
4164 gunicorn: worker [myproj.    22:53:54
4165 gunicorn: worker [myproj.    22:53:53
5207 grep --color=auto gunicorn        00:00
```

So gunicorn and all its workers have been running uninterrupted since ~1:01PM yesterday. The Nginx access log confirm that requests were successfully being served for about an hour after gunicorn was started. Then it seems for some reason both gunicorn sockets disappeared, and gunicorn continued running without writing any error logs.

Any ideas on what could cause that? Or how to fix it?

Comment: Hi there. I know this question is over a year old, but might you have found a solution in the mean time? I've been running into the exact same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out this was indeed a [bug](https://github.com/benoitc/gunicorn/issues/1139), where `eventlet` workers would delete the socket when they themselves would restart.

The fix has already been merged into master branch, but it has unfortunately not been released yet (version 19.3 still has the problem).